# Uploading large files to AWS Elastic Beanstalk / nginx

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application that uploads a file which works fine on Heroku and on local developer machines - but on AWS EB, the upload is interrupted and doesn't complete.

I've set the nginx directives as follows

**.ebextensions/00_project.config**

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            client_max_body_size 2000M
            client_body_buffer_size 2000M
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: server:application
```

**.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf**

```
client_max_body_size 2000M;
client_body_buffer_size 2000M;
```

**.platform/nginx/00_myconf.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

This is running python3.8 and using a plotly/react framework called Dash. https://dash.plotly.com/introduction

As mentioned, it's only not working on AWS so it appears to be a system config issue. To confirm this, I uploaded a large file to a public bucket and had this app read from the bucket instead of the upload and it worked fine.

I've exhausted all options so any help muchly appreciated!

Comment: What error code do you get, when the upload is interrupted? This will help you understand, if it is an nginx or a python issue.

Comment: there isn't an error to speak of. least none I can see... But your question prompted me to check the beanstalk logs where I saw this.
Dec  8 05:58:47 ip-172-31-7-149 web: MemoryError

Comment: and that error is in the web.stdout.log file. the nginx log looks ok but I did see this warning (however innocuous it looks) 

2021/12/08 05:57:22 [warn] 3988#3988: *158 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/4/00/0000000004 while reading upstream, client: 172.31.12.108, server: , request: "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash/dcc/async-plotlyjs.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/_dash-component-suites/dash/dcc/async-plotlyjs.js", host: "<removed>.removed.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "<removed>"

Comment: Increasing the instance size fixed it! kgiannakakis if you want to answer "upgrade your instance size by paying more money to AWS" then I will mark that as correct. If it wasnt for your comment I wouldn't have seen that error in the logs.

Comment: It would be more appropriate for you to write an answer and accept it. It is fine to answer your own questions. This may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

After prompting from kgiannakakis, I checked the logs and was found a "web: MemoryError" line in the web.stdout.log file.

So I upgraded the EB instance to something a bit bigger and it managed to fix the issue... so essentially I was running out of memory and needed to pay AWS more money to get more memory.